# pairwise independent

Tags: probability-theory

I came across this example:
Suppose Sam has to revise for an exam. He loves the sunshine so much that he  will revise only if its a rainy day, which will happen with probability 0.3, and evan then there is a 0.6 chance that he will procrastinate all day and get nothing done.What is the chance that he revises during the day?
Due to independence, the probability is 0.3*0.6= 0.18.
However, I cannot understand how this is an example of independent events. the fact that he revises depends on the weather according to the question or is it because there is also the probability that he will procrastinate?

Comment: Independence is not needed here and P(revises) is not .18. One is given P(revises|sunshine)=0 and P(procrastinates|rain)=.6 hence P(revises|rain)=1-.6=.4 and, using Bayes formula, one gets P(revises) as P(sunshine)*P(revises|sun)+P(rain)*P(revise|rain)=(.7).(0)+(.3).(.4)=.12.

Comment: ok thank you. now it makes sense. That came from a revision guide so maybe it was a misprint.